# Entire functions bounded on large wedges of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Define $W : [0,\infty) \to 2^{\mathbb{C}}$ by $W(\theta) = \{r\cdot \operatorname{exp}(i\cdot t) : \langle r,t \rangle \in (0,\infty) \times (-\theta,\theta)\}$.

For what $\theta$ does there exist an entire function $f$ such that $\{f(z) : z\in W(\theta)\}$ is bounded?

I know this holds for $\theta \leq \frac12 \cdot \pi$, because of $(z\mapsto \operatorname{exp}(-z))$,

and fails for $\pi \leq \theta$, because $W(\theta)$ would be dense.

Comment: Andrey Rekalo shows that the answer is all $\theta<\pi$ at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29734/can-an-entire-non-constant-function-be-bounded-on-only-a-finite-set-of-lines-thro/29736#29736

Comment: Examples of such functions are Mittag-Leffler functions, and they
are described in good textbooks on function theory or on special
functions. I propose to close the question. 