# A question of uniqueness

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ an harmonique function on $\Omega=(a,b)\times (0,+\infty)$ and boundary conditions :

$\displaystyle  u(a,y)=u(b,y)=0,\quad\forall y\geq 0$

$\displaystyle u(x,0)=0,\,\lim_{y\to +\infty} u(x,y)=0 \quad \forall x\in (a,b)$

Can we conclude that  $\quad u=0$ on $\Omega$ ?

My adempt

Let $$\Omega_{R}=(a,b)\times (0,R),\forall R>0$$By IBP, i show that
$$\int_{\Omega_R}u\Delta u=\int_a^{b}u(x,R)\frac{du}{dy}(x,R)dx-\int_{\Omega_R}|\nabla u|^2 $$ Thus
$$\forall R>0,\quad \int_{\Omega_R}|\nabla u|^2=\int_a^bu(x,R)\frac{du}{dy}(x,R)dx$$

I need help to cointinuous ( For example to show  $\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2=0$)

**edit Continuing the initial reasoning,** with $a=0$  and $b=\pi$ as suggested by A Ermenko

$\Big(\int_{\Omega_R}|\nabla u|^2\Big)^2=\Big(\int_0^{\pi}u(x,R)\frac{du}{dy}(x,R)dx\Big)^2\\
\leq \int_0^{\pi}u(x,R)^2dx\int_0^{\pi}\Big(\frac{du}{dy}(x,R)\Big)^2dx ,\mbox{by Cauchy–Schwarz inequality
}\\\\$

$\leq  \int_0^{\pi}u(x,R)^2dx \int_0^{\pi}|\nabla u|^2(x,R)dx \\\\$

$= \int_0^{\pi}u(x,R)^2dx\int_{]0,\pi[\times\{R\}}|\nabla u|^2 \\\\$

$\leq  \int_0^{\pi}u(x,R)^2dx \int_{\Omega_R}|\nabla u|^2,\mbox{because} ]0,\pi[\times\{R\}\subset\Omega_R$

Then $$\int_{\Omega_R}|\nabla u|^2\leq \int_0^{\pi}u(x,R)^2.$$ I can only conclude if $\displaystyle ||u(.,R)||_{L^2]0,\pi[}\to^{R\to\infty} 0$

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use maximum principle?

Comment: Anyway, for the method you choose: $u(x,R) \frac{du}{dy}(x,R) = \frac12 \frac{d}{dy} |u(x,y)|^2 \Big]_{y = R}$. If the lim of $u(x,y)$ tends to zero, there exists some $R$ for which the integral of this derivative is negative.

Comment: @Willie Wong the maximum principale is available if $\Omega$ a bounded domain theoreme 2.17 https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch2.pdf

Comment: Let $\Omega_t = \Omega \cap \{ y < t\}$. Apply the maximum principle for $u$ on $\Omega_t$. Take $t\to \infty$.

Comment: @Willie Wong I tried to apply the maximum principle with your indication with $ \Omega_t $ but without success. Can you give your answer because I do not see why it is easy and especially that A.Ermenko says that there is a counter example.

Comment: @cerise: I had taken your convergence $\lim_{y\to\infty} u(x,y) = 0$ to mean convergence with respect to some reasonable function norm (say $L^\infty$). If you only wished to have pointwise convergence and no more, then as Eremenko said there are counterexamples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the positive answer you should state your last condition more carefully.
For example, add that $u$ is bounded, or that $u(x+iy)$ tends to $0$ as $y\to\infty$
UNIFORMLY with respect to $x$.

As you presently stated, the answer is negative. I sketch the construction of a counterexample.

1. There exists a non-zero entire function, real on the real line and such that $f(re^{i\theta})\to 0$ as $r\to+\infty$ for every $\theta$. (See, for example, my answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190837/entire-function-bounded-at-every-line/190875#190875), which explains how to construct $f$.)
2. $v(z)=\Im f(z)$ is a non-zero harmonic function in the upper half-plane, equal to $0$ on
   the real line and $u(re^{i\theta})\to 0$ as $r\to+\infty$ for every $\theta\in(0,\pi)$.
3. Take without loss of generality $a=0,\; b=\pi$, then $e^{-i(z-\pi)}$
   maps your strip $0<z<\pi$ into the upper half-plane, with a removed half-disk.
   So the function $w(z)=v(e^{-i(z-\pi)})$ is harmonic, zero on infinite sides
   of your half-strip and satisfies the property at $\infty$:
   $w(x+iy)\to 0$ as $y\to+\infty$ for every $x\in(0,\pi)$. Notice that this function is unbounded. To satisfy the last requirement, that $u(x)=0$ for $0<x<\pi$,
   set $u(z)=w(z)-w_1(z)$, where $w_1(z)$ is the solution of Dirichlet problem matching
   the boundary values of $w$ on the finite part of the boundary and bounded in your strip.

Remark. Since every simply connected domain other than the plane is conformally equivalent to the unit disk, your question is equivalent to the following. Suppose that $u$ is harmonic in the unit disk and $\lim_{z\to\zeta} u(z)=0$ for all $\zeta\in\{ \zeta:|\zeta|=1\}\backslash\{1\}$, and moreover $u(z)\to 0$ along any non-tangential segment ending at $1$, that is $u(1-re^{i\theta})\to 0,\; r\to 0$ for every $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Does it follow that $u=0$? The answer is NO.

Comment: @ A.Eremenko I think you are right, assumptions are missing, I edited my post. I have not yet understood the construction of a counter example

Comment: @cerise: I do not see how you edited your post, but if you add one of the conditions that I suggested, the counterexample will loose its meaning.

Comment: @ A.Eremenko I edited to continue my reasoning and didn't add anything as additional assumptions. I noticed that the answer is positive to the question if $\displaystyle ||u(.,R)||_{L^2]0,\pi[}\to^{R\to\infty} 0$

Comment: conflicting opinions of experts, does not help me.

Comment: @cerise: your conclusion that $\| u(,.R)\|_2\to 0,\; R\to\infty$ is incorrect: it does not hold in my example. From your assumptions AS STATED it does NOT follow that $u=0$. Look in the literature about "passing to the limit under the integral sign".

Comment: @A.Eremenko   I said  I can only conclude if $\displaystyle ||u(.,R)||_{L^2]0,\pi[}\to^{R\to\infty} 0$. in the sense: if I assume this hypothesis of more