# Ratio of measure of level region for harmonic functions

Tags: harmonic-functions

Let $u$ be a harmonic function defined on $B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, $u(0)=0$, and $\{x\in B_1(0):u(x)>0\}$ is simply connected. Is there a universal constant $c>0$ satisfying that
$$
c\leq \frac{m(B_1(0)\cap\{u(x)>0\} )}{m(B_1(0)\cap\{u(x)<0\} )}\leq c^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative. To construct a counterexample, use an entire function $f$ which satisfies $|f(z)|<1$ in ${\mathbf{C}}\backslash D$, where $D$ is a half-strip $\{ x+iy:x>0,|y|<\pi \}$. Then $v={\mathrm{Re}}f-1$ is harmonic, and negative in ${\mathbf{C}}\backslash D$. Let $D_1=\{ z: u(z)>0\}\subset D$, and
$z_1\in\partial D_1$. Then $v_1(z)=v(z-1)$ satisfies $v_1(0)=0$ and for sufficiently large $R$, $u(z)=v_1(Rz)$ will be positive on a subset of the unit disk of arbitrarily small area.

A function $f$ with required property can be constructed as a Cauchy integral
$$f(z)=\int_{\partial D}\frac{e^{e^\zeta}d\zeta}{\zeta-z},$$
for details about this construction, see, for example
W. Hayman, Meromorphic functions, Chap. 4, 4.1.
See also [Entire function bounded at every line](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190837/entire-function-bounded-at-every-line/190874#190874)

Comment: But I'm wondering if the positive part $\{x\in B_1(0): u(x)>0\}$ of such a harmonic function $u(z)$ is always simply connected?

Comment: Each component of the set $\{ z:u(z)>0\}$ for any harmonic function is simply connected; this followd from the Maximum/Minimum Principle. But the number of components can be large.

Comment: Then the positive part is not simply connected in this example, which does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: I repeat that the set $\{ z:u(z)>0\}$ is ALWAYS simply connected.

Comment: Oh, you are right and I am afraid I forgot to assume $\{z: u(z)>0\}$ is also a region.

Comment: @Sam and Jim: do you also want $\{ z:u(z)<0\}$ to be connected?

Comment: Yes! I have been wondering if there is any proof or counterexample of this case ( the positive part and negative part are both connected)

Comment: The conjecture is that if both { z:u(z)>0} and { z: u(z)<0} are connected then your assertion about areas must be true. But if only one of them is connected, probably not. Both statements look plausible but difficult to prove.