# Carleman's Liouville theorem for entire functions bounded along every ray

Tags: cv.complex-variables, harmonic-functions

There is a long history on constructing entire functions bounded along every direction. For example, we refer to Burckel's math review on Newman (Amer. Math. Monthly 1976 MR0387593) or this [mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190837/entire-function-bounded-at-every-line)

There is a Liouville theorem on such functions (first discovered by Carleman)

**Theorem 1:[Carleman 1926]**
Let $f(z)$ be an entire function so that
$$
|f(re^{i\theta})| \leq L(\theta), \ \ \theta \in [0, 2\pi).
$$
where $L(\theta)$ is a measurable function on $[0, 2\pi)$ with
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \log^{+} \log^{+} L(\theta) d\theta<+\infty, \ \ \text{where for any given}\ x \in \mathbb{R}, \ \log^{+}x=\begin{cases} \ln x \ \ x \geq 1\\ 0 \ \ x \leq 1\\\end{cases}.
$$
Then $f$ is constant.

*Carleman, T.. Extension d'un th'{e}or`{e}me de liouville. Acta Math. 48, 3-4 (1926), 363--366.*

**Theorem 2: [Levinson and many people]**
Consider a rectangle
$$
\Omega=\{z=x+yi\ |\ x \in (a_1, a_2), y \in (-b, b)\}
$$ and $L(y)$ is a measurable function on $(-b, b)$ with
$$
\int_{-b}^b \log^{+} \log^{+} L(y) dy<+\infty.
$$
Then for any compact subset $K \subset \Omega$, there exists a constant $C$ depending only on $L(y)$ and $\operatorname{dist}(K, \partial \Omega)$ so that for any holomorphic function in $\Omega$ with $|f(x+yi)| \leq L(y)$ we always have
$$
|f(z)| \leq C, \ \ \text{for any}\ z \in K.
$$
Moreover, $C$ is decreasing with respect to $\operatorname{dist}(K, \partial \Omega)$.

Obviously Theorem 1 is a special case of Theorem 2 (like the connection between three-circle theorem and three-line theorem). Theorem 2 is proved by establishing similar result on $\ln |f|$, we may refer to Domar's beautiful proof (also presented in Koosis's book) of Theorem 2.

*Koosis, P. The logarithmic integral. I., vol. 12 of Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1998.*

From a historical perspective, I am interested in Carleman's original proof. His 1926 paper was written in French. I have some difficulty in understanding arguments there. Let me summarize in below, following notations in his original paper.

**Notations:**
$$
M(r)=\sup_{\varphi \in[0, 2\pi)} |f(re^{i\varphi}), \ \ln M(r)=v(r), \ \ln |f(\rho e^{i\varphi})|=U(\rho, \varphi)
$$
$$ 
|f(re^{i\theta})| \leq L(\theta) \doteq e^{e^{\omega(\theta)}}, \ \int_0^{2\pi} \omega(\theta)d\theta<\infty.
$$

For any given $r>0$, we pick a corresponding $\xi_{r}=r e^{i \theta_r}$ so that $|f(re^{i\theta_r})|=M(r)$. Moreover, we choose $\xi_{r-\delta}=(r-\delta)e^{i\theta_{r-\delta}}$ so that $|f(\xi_{r-\delta})|=M(r-\delta)$ and $\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \xi_{r-\delta}=\xi_r$. Roughly speaking, we need a continuous path in the set of maximum modulus.

Now a fixed $r>0$, we pick a subdomain $D=\{z=\rho e^{i\varphi}, |\rho|<r, U(\rho, \varphi)>\frac{1}{2}v(r)\}$ so that $\xi_r \in \partial D$. In the meantime, we make sure $\partial D$ consists of two parts $\gamma  \cup L$ where $U(\rho, \varphi) \geq \frac{1}{2}v(r)$ on $\gamma \subset \partial D(0, r)$, and $U(\rho, \varphi) = \frac{1}{2}v(r)$ on $L \subset D(0, r)$ respectively, Next we use $W(\rho, \varphi)$ to denote the harmonic measure of $\gamma$ with respect to $\partial D(0, r)$ at $\rho e^{i\varphi}$.

Pick $r$ large enough so that $v(r)>0$. Now we have $U(\rho, \varphi)-\frac{1}{2}v(r)-\frac{1}{2}v(r) W(\rho, \varphi) \leq 0$ on $\partial D$. By maximum principle (for subharmonic functions) we have inside $D$,
$$
U(\rho, \varphi)-\frac{1}{2}v(r)-\frac{1}{2}v(r) W(\rho, \varphi) \leq 0.
$$
Plug into $\rho=r-\delta$ and $\varphi=\theta_{r-\delta}$ and we get
$$
v(\rho-\delta)-\frac{1}{2}v(r)-\frac{1}{2}v(r) W(r-\delta, \theta_{r-\delta}) \leq 0.
$$
If we assume the total length of $\gamma$ is $2\pi \theta$, it is well known that
$$
W(\rho, \varphi) \leq h(\rho) \doteq \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan \Big( \frac{r+\rho}{r-\rho} \tan (\frac{\theta}{2})\Big)
$$
Then
$$
v(\rho-\delta)-\frac{1}{2}v(r)-\frac{1}{2}v(r) h(r-\delta) \leq 0.
$$ which means
$$
v(r)-v(\rho-\delta) \geq \frac{1}{2}v(r)(h(r)-h(r-\delta))
$$ where we use $h(r)=1$.
Therefore whenever $v(r)$ is differentiable, we have
$$
v'(r) \geq \frac{1}{2}v(r)h'(r)=\frac{1}{2}v(r) \frac{\cot(\frac{\theta}{2})}{\pi r}.
$$

Now we reparametrize and introduce $s=\ln r$ and $g(s)=\ln{\frac{v(r)}{2}}$, then the above differential inequality becomes
$$
\frac{dg(s)}{ds} \geq \frac{1}{2\pi \tan(\frac{\theta}{2})}.
$$
If we introduce
$$
\lambda(s)=\text{Measure} \{ \varphi \in [0, 2\pi], \ |\  \omega(\varphi) \geq g(s)\},
$$
Obviously $\lambda(s) \geq Length(\gamma)=2\pi \theta$ as any point $re^{i\varphi} \in \gamma$ we have
$$
\omega(\varphi) \geq \ln U(r, \varphi) \geq \ln (\frac{v(r)}{2})=g(s).
$$

**Claim 1:** $$
\frac{dg(s)}{ds} \geq \frac{1}{2\pi \tan(\frac{\theta}{2})} \geq \frac{k}{\lambda(s)}
$$ for some constant $k>0$.

Once Claim 1 holds, we have $\lambda dg \geq k ds$. After integration
$$
\int_{g_0}^{\infty} \lambda dg \geq \lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}k(s-s_0)=\infty
$$

On the other hand,

**Claim 2:**
$$
\int_{g_0}^{\infty} \lambda dg =-\int_0^{\infty} g d\lambda \leq \int_0^{2\pi} \omega(\varphi)d\varphi<\infty
$$ Here we note $\lambda(s)$ is non-increasing on $s$.

Once Claim 1 and 2 hold, Theorem 1 follows.

**Question 1:** How do we prove Claim 1? It seems we need to show $\theta(r)$ is uniformly bounded by some angle strictly smaller than $\pi$, so that $\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}$ is bounded from below. This point is unclear to me.

**Question 2:** How do we prove Claim 2? Namely why does the integration by parts hold and how do we compare compare $d\lambda$ and $d\varphi$?

Another minor issue is that in the proof it is assumed $v(r)=\ln M(r)$ is differentiable with respect to $r$, and there is a continuous path in the set of maximum modulus from the inside.

Thanks for any answers or suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

It is not completely clear from the question whether your interest is mathematical or historical. Are you primarily interested in a proof of this theorem, or mostly in what Carleman wrote in this particular note. Anyway, I propose you to look in this paper:

MR2567024
Rashkovskii, Alexander
Classical and new loglog-theorems,
Expo. Math. 27 (2009), no. 4, 271–287.

where the authors discuss this result and its subsequent . With simple proofs.

Comment: Dear Alexandre, Yes, originally I am just curious, now I want to understand Carleman’s proof mathematically. I think his proof is of some simple beauty once two claims I listed can be explained. I found his paper in Acta Math 1926 (detailed info listed in my question following his statement). Not sure if he had another note in C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris.

Comment: Can I ask if you have time to explain two claims I asked? I happened to see your earlier paper with Sodin (Complex Variables 1989) used parts of Carleman’s argument. I will check the paper you recommend.

Comment: @Bo_Y: Yes, it is in Acta, but very short. This is the only paper of Carleman on the subj. (I have his Complete works).